# PHP cURL to POST works, but not when I POST without cURL - What am I missing?

Tags: php, http, post, curl

I am in a situation where I cannot use PHP cURL module to POST my form data. I have found a great blog post showing how to POST without using cURL here:
[HTTP POST from PHP, without cURL](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl)

Here's my problem though. When I attempt to send my POST request, the request hits the (other) server but the content (POST data) is not transmitted. The other server does not get the content. HOWEVER, if I do use cURL, it works fine. What am I missing? How can I recreate the cURL HTTP POST request without using cURL?

Here is the cURL code that works ($this->params is just $_POST which contains the form data):

```
$ch = curl_init($this->url);

$params = http_build_query($this->params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $result;
```

And here is my non-cURL version that does not work:

```
$postStr = http_build_query($this->params);

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method' => $method,
        //'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        //'header' => 'content-type: multipart/form-data',
        'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content-encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'content' => $postStr
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($this->url, false, $context);

return $result;
```

There are no errors or warnings. Just, the accepting server doesn't appear to the contents. Any ideas?

Comment: Just use curl. Any reason you want to make it hard on yourself? Enjoy reinvention of the wheel?

Comment: his hosting may be limited...a lot of free/shared hosting does not allow cURL

Comment: indeed. libcurl, while quite common, is not necessarily standard. this is especially true on non-linux unices and IIS.

Comment: Yes, it's a hosting limitation. Despite my best efforts to have them upgrade... They won't. And before you ask... Changing hosts is not an option.
So reinventing the wheel it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely your `$method` is not populated with `'POST'`. The other major reason would have been an  open_basedir restriction, but that would have generated a warning.

Try explicitly naming "POST"

```
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content-encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'content' => $postStr
    )
);
```

Comment: Ah! Ok, so it was a simple case-sensitivity mistake. The $method was set to 'post' instead of 'POST'. Oh geesh... Thank you for taking the time to help! It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

**Your non-CURL version is incomplete**.

you must use `fopen` after creating the context with `stream_context_create`.

**Solution: Use this function:** Do it like this:

```
<?php
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));

  if ($optional_headers !== null)
      $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;

  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);

  if (!$fp)
      throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");

  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);

  if ($response === false)
      throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");

  return $response;
}
```

Comment: The function: file_get_contents() replaces the need for fopen. You can see a different example (than the one in the blog) here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php